# Каким образом сократить проверку на v-bind:class?

Tags: vue.js

Каким образом можно сократить этот список?

```
    <ul class="paginator__list">
      <li v-bind:class="{ active: CURRENTPAGE === 1 }">1</li>
      <li v-bind:class="{ active: CURRENTPAGE === 2 }">2</li>
      <li v-bind:class="{ active: CURRENTPAGE === 3 }">3</li>
      <li v-bind:class="{ active: CURRENTPAGE === 4 }">4</li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<ul class="paginator__list">
  <li v-for="i in 4" :class="{ active: CURRENTPAGE === i }">{{ i }}</li>
</ul>
```